# minio mc cp <ERROR> Unable to validate source

Tags: docker, docker-compose, minio

I have a docker-compose project, which creates a Minio Service and an mc service, to create a new bucket and upload a file which is within the minio container in the data/ directory.

creating the bucket is not problem, but when I want to copy the file in it, I am getting the error: `mc: <ERROR> Unable to validate source myminio/data/yellow_tripdata_2022-01.parquet.`

The complete output from the mc service is:

```
test3-createbuckets-1  | Added `myminio` successfully.
test3-createbuckets-1  | Bucket created successfully `myminio/sample-lakehouse`.
test3-createbuckets-1  | mc: <ERROR> Unable to validate source`myminio/data/yellow_tripdata_2022-01.parquet`.
```

test3-createbuckets-1 exited with code 0

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  minio:
    image: minio/minio:latest
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"
    volumes:
      - ./minio-data:/data
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: test
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: test12334567
    command: server /data --console-address ":9001"

  createbuckets:
    image: minio/mc
    depends_on:
      - minio
    entrypoint: >
      /bin/sh -c "
      sleep 60;
      /usr/bin/mc config host add myminio http://minio:9000 test test12334567;
      /usr/bin/mc mb myminio/sample-lakehouse;
      /usr/bin/mc cp myminio/data/yellow_tripdata_2022-01.parquet myminio/sample-lakehouse/yellow_tripdata_2022-01.parquet;
      exit 0;
      "

volumes:
  minio-data:
    driver: local
```

Does someone have an Idea, why this error occurs? The alias myminio seems to be valid.